# Ask User's Password When Logging with Social Account - Laravel Socialite

Tags: laravel, laravel-socialite

I have fully functional Socialite social login with Google and Facebook but i want to add another step that is "ask a password before logging in".

This function logs the user immediately after successfully logging in with the provider:

```
public function callback(Request $request, $provider, SocialAccountsService $service)
    {
        if ($request->has("error")) {
            return redirect()->route("website.index");
        }

        try {

            $user = $service->createOrGetUser(
                Socialite::driver($provider)->user(),
                $provider
            );

            auth()->login($user);

        } catch (InvalidStateException $e) {
            Log::error($e->getMessage());
            return redirect()->route("auth.register.index");
        }

        return redirect()->route("dashboard.profile.index");
    }
```

What should i do so when they login with the provider they must insert a password before logging to my website?

Comment: You want them to login, so they can login with their login? What have you tried? Just make them insert a password before logging in? Where to start? Break your issue down! Do you know how to make an if statement? Do you know how to return a view? Create a HTML? Help us help you.

Comment: something like "keep the social email but make a new password", logging in without password should not be a permitted @NicklasKevinFrank

Answer (score -1):

Okey, you want to create user but do not want to log it. Than:

- Delete `auth()->login($user);`
- Add something like `session()->put('created_social_user_id', $user->id);`
- Create `PasswordCreation` controller and view and redirect user from callback to it
- In this controller - use session, get user_id, find before created model and ask user about password.
- After password creation - add `auth()->login($user);` and redirect to dashboard